# Regex in python: combining 2 regex expressions into one

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have the following list:

```
a = ['35','years','opened','7,000','churches','rev.','mr.','brandt','said','adding','denomination','national','goal','one','church','every','10,000','persons']
```

I want to remove all elements, that contain numbers and elements, that end with dots.
So I want to delete `'35','7,000','10,000','mr.','rev.'`

I can do it separately using the following regex:

```
regex = re.compile('[a-zA-Z\.]')
regex2 = re.compile('[0-9]')
```

But when I try to combine them I delete either all elements or nothing.
How can I combine two regex correctly?

Comment: "I can do it separately using the following regex:" -- I am sorry but I don't believe you. The regex `[a-zA-Z\.]` matches any single character in that set, and so it will **NOT** only remove "elements, that end with dots". It will *also* remove every upper and lowercase letter in your entire string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

`reg = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]+\.|[0-9,]+')`

Note that your first regex is wrong because it deletes any string within a dot inside it.
To avoid this, I included `[a-zA-Z]+\.` in the combined regex.
Your second regex is also wrong as it misses a "+" and a ",", which I included in the above solution.
Here a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tLflPE/1).

Also, if you assume that elements which end with a dot might contain some numbers the complete solution should be:

`reg = re.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.|[0-9,]+')`

Comment: @liverToll92: This [doesn't work](https://regex101.com/r/c4vATv/2)

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
(?:[^\d\n]*\d)|.*\.$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Tr8Dxk/2).

Comment: This doesn't match `35` or `7,000`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to capture the result, this matches any string with a dot at the end, or any with a number in it.

```
\.$|\d
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do the job:

```
import re

a = ['35','years','opened','7,000','churches','rev.','mr.','brandt','said','adding','denomination','national','goal','one','church','every','10,000','per.sons']
b = []
for s in a:
    if not re.search(r'^(?:[\d,]+|.*\.)$', s):
        b.append(s)
print b
```

**Output:**

```
['years', 'opened', 'churches', 'brandt', 'said', 'adding', 'denomination', 'national', 'goal', 'one', 'church', 'every', 'per.sons']
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/c4vATv/1)